# Magento 1 noindex cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I am finding the shopping cart page of my store is being indexed. How can I noindex the URL https://www.example.com.au/checkout/cart/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add following code in `checkout.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Its Work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using event observer as follows :
**app/code/local/Custom/MetaChange/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_MetaChange>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_MetaChange>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <metaChange>
                <class>Custom_MetaChange_Model</class>
            </metaChange>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
                <observers>
                    <noindex>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>metaChange/observer</class>
                        <method>changeRobots</method>
                    </noindex>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/MetaChange/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_MetaChange_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function changeRobots($observer) {

            if ($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index') {
                $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
                $product_info = $layout->getBlock('head');
                $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="head"><action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX, FOLLOW</value></action></reference>');
                $layout->generateXml();
            }

        return $this;
    }

}
```